# ionic2 ModalController can not show in websocket

Tags: ionic2, sockjs

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Events, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import { SomePage } from './somepage';

export class DashboardPage {
    sockjs: any;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        public events: Events,
        private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

        this.initWebsocket();
    }

    initWebsocket() {
        this.sockjs = new SockJS('http://192.168.0.141:8080/ws-driver');

        this.sockjs.onopen = function () {
            console.log('open');
        };
        this.sockjs.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log('message', e.data);
            alert('ok');
            let model = this.modalCtrl.create(SomePage);
            model.present();
        };
        this.sockjs.onclose = function () {
            console.log('close');
        };
    }
}
```

alert('ok') had been process.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of `function` keyword as `this` within the function refers to `function object`.
Try:

```
 this.sockjs.onmessage = (e)=> {
            console.log('message', e.data);
            alert('ok');
            let model = this.modalCtrl.create(SomePage);
            model.present();
        };
```

Or set `self=this;`

```
let self = this;
 this.sockjs.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log('message', e.data);
            alert('ok');
            let model = self.modalCtrl.create(SomePage);
            model.present();
        };
```